# Unable to use VBA code for filtering data that begins with both numerical and alphabetic characters

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which is working except one line.

I am trying to filter a csv report. The data is in a column and begins with both numerical and alphabetic characters.

`(=I6*,=I7*,=IA*,=IP*,=IH*,=II*)  OR  (=6*,=7*,=A*,=IP*,=H*,=I*)`   only

Code I tried:

```
.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("=6**", "=7**", "=A**", "=P**", "=H**", "=I**"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

or:

```
.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:=Array("=I6**", "=I7**", "=IA**", "=IP**", "=IH**", "=II**"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```